# How to Concatenate Column Values in one column to another tablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Extracting data from MySQL (name ,sex, age, city ) (sex=1 or 2 , age = 1 to 6 agegroup and cite by code). Now I want concatenate sex, age and city codes with (day month year) into barcoding column (anther tablewidget_2) according appearing in table widget_1 and result for example should be like this 132612052019 (sex code+age code+city code +date).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pymysql
import random

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="bdr654321", database="badr")
        self.mycur = self.conn.cursor()

    def loaddata(self):
        sex = self.lineEdit.text()
        age = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        city = self.lineEdit_3.text()

        result = self.mycur.execute("SELECT * FROM example WHERE age = '%s' AND city = '%s' " % (''.join(age), ''.join(city)))
        res = self.mycur.fetchall()

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(res):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        return
        self.conn.close()

    def showmessagebox(self, title, message):
        mesgbox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        mesgbox.seticon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Warning)
        mesgbox.setWindowTitle(title)
        mesgbox.setText(message)
        mesgbox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.OK)
        mesgbox.exec()

    def search(self):
        name_1 = self.lineEdit_5.text()
        result_1 = self.mycur.execute("SELECT * FROM example WHERE name='%s' " % (''.join(name_1)))
        res_1 = self.mycur.fetchall()

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(res_1):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        return
        self.conn.close()

    def randdata(self):
        rand_1 = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        age = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        city = self.lineEdit_3.text()

        result_2 = self.mycur.execute( "SELECT * FROM example WHERE age = '%s' AND city = '%s' " % (''.join(age), ''.join(city)))
        res_2 = self.mycur.fetchall()

        random_2 = random.sample(res_2, k=int(rand_1))

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(random_2):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))




        return
        self.conn.close()





    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1312, 852)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 821, 401))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 171, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 80, 101, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 80, 113, 41))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 68, 19))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 68, 19))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 50, 68, 19))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 80, 113, 41))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 18, 191, 51))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 121, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loaddata)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(757, 40, 161, 41))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 80, 181, 41))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 590, 161, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 590, 211, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 150, 191, 401))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1060, 150, 256, 401))
        self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
        self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 600, 761, 192))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 650, 448, 289))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1030, 30, 171, 41))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 560, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 560, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(940, 80, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.search)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 80, 112, 34))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.randdata)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sex"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Age"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "City"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "barcode(of item)"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "lat"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "long"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sex"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Age"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "City"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "No of sample random"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search by name"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "print barcode"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "export file(cvs file)"))
        item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "barcodeing"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "map"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "edit data"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "search"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "random"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From your first problem I understood that you want a column of the second QTableWidget to show the text concatenation of some columns of the first QTableWidget, but of your second request I did not understand anything.

Comment: yes for first. for second I want convert code number to barcode to do print for barcode

Comment: In SO you should ask a question for POST, that's why the button says "Ask Question", it does not say "Ask Questions"